# Isomorphism of cotangent bundles..

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (may be almost complex, almost Kahler, Kahler..). 
and Let $\phi : T^*M \rightarrow T^*M$ be a cotangent bundle automorphism. (the restriction of $\phi$ on the base $M$ is just the identity)
Then it maps 1-forms to 1-forms. Moreover, $\phi$ can be canonically extended to the isomorphism of $\Lambda T^*M$, bundle of differential forms.

Question. Is there any criterion whether $\phi$ commutes with $d$ or not? ( I mean, I want to know when $\phi$ gives an isomorphism of de Rham cohomology ring $H^*(M)$)

Comment: Maybe I am confused by your question, but a bundle isomorphism induces a diffeomorphism $f: M \to M$ over the base, and the exterior derivative $d$ always commutes with pullback by a diffeomorphism. Is there something else that you mean here? 

Comment: Spiro: your choice of wording bothers me ("induces").  I would say that part of the data of a bundle isomorphism is a diffeomorphism of the base and that since the exterior derivative always commutes with a pullback by a diffeomorphism, you can use the base map to reduce the problem to that of an isomorphism of $T^* M$ covering the _identity_.  But there's still a question to answer there since there can be several of those.

Comment: You're right, I used the wrong word. It is indeed part of the data of a bundle map. I just understood the question, actually. In general, of course, the answer is no. Consider for example, the bundle map which is multiplication by -1 on each fibre of $T^* M$. Then the induced map on $\Lambda T*M$ will be +1 on even forms and -1 on odd forms. Since $d$ changes degree, we have $d \phi \alpha \neq \phi d \alpha$ for any $k$-form $\alpha$. I would have to think about it for a general criterion. It's not immediately obvious.

Comment: Above, $\Lambda T*M$ should of course be $\Lambda T^*M$. I still don't know how to edit my own comments. Is that possible?

Also, I just realized the actual question was not about whether $\phi$ would always commute with $d$, so I shouldn't have said the answer to the question is no. (It's 7am for me, and my brain doesn't work at these hours...)

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I mean. For example, If $g_t$ is a 1-parametrized family of Riemannian metric ($t \in [0,1]$) on $M$, then we can construct a bundle automorphism $\phi$ of $TM$ such that $\phi^* g_1 = g_0$. Of course there are many such kind of automorphisms. I want to know when the induced cotangent bundle automorphism preserves the differential $d$. 

Comment: $\phi$ commutes with $d$ if and only if $\phi$ is the identity. Proof: 
If $\phi$ commutes with $d$, then $\phi(df)=d (\phi f)=d (\phi (f\cdot 1))$. Since $\phi$ is a bundle homomorphism, $d (\phi (f\cdot 1)) = d (f \phi (1))$. Since $\phi(1)=1$, this is $df$. Or did I miss something in your question?

Comment: Johannes: $phi$ is a vector bundle isomorphism, so on each fibre of $T^* M$ it is a linear map, but the induced map on $\Lambda^0 T^* M = M \times \mathbb R$ is necessarily the identity map. What you have shown is that for $\phi$ to commute with $d$, it must be the identity on exact $1$-forms. But that does not imply that it is the identity on all $1$-forms.

Comment: @Spiro: but any 1-form is a linear combination of exact ones.

Comment: Yes, Michael is correct. I wasn't thinking it through completely. I noticed that Anton Deitmar posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The question is local. Therefore it can be answered in coordinates. On functions, $\phi$ acts trivially. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be local coordinates. Then $dx_i=d(\phi\circ x_j)=\phi(dx_j)$, which implies that $\phi$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "never"
(except for the trivial case of
a multiplication by a constant). Suppose 
that you have coordinates $x_1, ..., x_n$ on M.
Then $x_i dx_i$ is closed, hence
$x_i \phi(dx_i)$ is also closed.
Therefore, $dx_i \wedge \phi(dx_i)=0$,
hence $\phi(dx_i) = f_i dx_i$.
Since this is true for each linear
combination $\sum \alpha_i dx_i$,
the function $f_i$ is the same for
all $i$. Therefore, $\phi(dx_i)=fdx_i$.
However, since $\phi(dx_i)$ is closed,
$f$ is a constant.